# Supressing empty Subreports in Crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Problem:
I want to suppress the DetailsSection 4 and 5  if there are no records in Subreports in them.So the problem is that I can supress them if they are no rows in the table of that subreport. but when there are rows , I see that the report is so big and repeating itself many times. I can see the report with all the sections repeating again and again when there is data.

I have a Crystal report with 5 Subreports as follows.

1. reportHeader
2. PageHeader
3. DetailsSection1(Subreport1 Here)
4. DetailsSection2(Subreport2 Here)
5. DetailsSection3(Subreport3 Here)
6. DetailsSection4(ApplicantInformation Here)
7. DetailsSection5(CBInformation  Here)
8. PageFooter
9. ReportFooter

The steps I followed are :

Step:1 (Collected the total records of table ApplicantInformation in this shared var)

```
Create a shared Variable AppInfoCount with the following content in the formula

WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar AppCount;
AppCount := count({ApplicantInformation.DirectionID});
""
```

Step 2 :Used this variable for suppressing the detailsection4 in the Main report.

```
So In the Section Expert-->DetailSection4--> 
under Supress(No Drill-down)(x-2) I gave the formula 
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar AppCount;
if( AppCount= 0 ) then True else false;
```

I did all this in the Main report and not sub report. Is there something that I am missing? please help and thanks for those active helpers.

Regards,
Chandanan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than create detail sections for the `ApplicantInformation` and `CBInformation` sub reports create two more report footer sections. And put the sub reports there

Comment: Si Detail Section different from report Section? When I went to section expert and selected detail and said add then it inserted another detail below the existing one. Here is a snap shot.

Comment: Sorry I meant report **footer** I updated the answer to reflect that

Comment: How does that matter here? You mean to add the reports in footer nad if we have more reports keep on adding them with many footers?

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood your problem, yes. If you want the Sub-Report to only appear once this is an easy way to go. I have reports 6 report footers each with a subreport in it.

Comment: Yup you are right. that fixed my problem of repetition. You are the man!! Thanks a ton.